# solution to $\iiint\limits_\Omega (x+y+z)^2 dv, \Omega: x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 1$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$I=\iiint\limits_\Omega  (x+y+z)^2 dv, \Omega: x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 1$$

My attempt $$ I=\int_0^{2\pi} d \theta \int_0^{\pi} \sin\varphi d\varphi \int_0^1r^2(r\sin\varphi \cos \theta + r\sin\varphi \sin\theta +r\cos\varphi)^2 dr$$
I have to stop at this step because is is too difficult for me to integrate this complex integral.
Any hint how to resolve it in a simpler approach?

Comment: **Hint:** By symmetry, all the cross product terms integrate to zero.

Comment: cross product terms mean xy or yz or xz? This [page](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/CrossProduct.aspx) talking about it about I am still confused what do you mean.

Answer (score 1):

How did you get your work so far? If you expand your integrand you have,
$(x+y+z)^2=x^2+y^2+z^2+2xy+2yz+2xz$ converting this into spherical coordinates, $r^2+2r^2(cos(\theta)sin(\theta)sin^2(\phi)+cos(\theta)sin(\phi)cos(\phi)+sin(\theta)sin(\phi)cos(\phi))$. Thus you should integrate that over $r \in [0,1]$, $\theta \in [0,\pi]$, and $\phi \in [0,2\pi]$.  I will give one last hint and it is that you should use Fubini's Theorem to consider the $\phi$ $\theta$ integrals first on the cross terms.

Comment: I am still not sure how to use [Fubini's Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FubiniTheorem.html) here. Does $\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$ means cross terms?